# How do I get these elements to effectively center properly and responsively?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I feel like the solution I'm using is really hashed together and goopy. Let me know what I can do better, because I'm stuck on this one, short of rebuilding it from the ground up:

```
  <div id="content">
      <div class="blocking"
        <td><a href="https://github.com/kfrncs"><img src="img/github.png" class="social" id="github"></a></td>
        <td><a href="https://twitter.com/kfrncs"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="social" id="twitter"></a></td>
      </div>
      <div class="blocking">
        <td><a href="mailto:kennethpatrickfrancis@gmail.com"><img src="img/gmail.png" class="social" id="gmail"></a></td>
        <td><a href="skype:kennethpatrickfrancis?add"><img src="img/skype.png" class="social middle" id="skype"></a></td>
      </div>
      <div class="blocking">
        <td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2837229/kfrncs"><img src="img/stackoverflow.png" class="social" id="stackoverflow"></a></td>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .blocking {
        display: block;
        padding: 2vh 25vw 0 30vw;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #github {
        margin-top: 5vh;
    }
    #stackoverflow {
        margin-bottom: 5vh;
    }
    .titleres {
        display: block;
    }
}



@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)
{
    .blocking {
        display: block;
        padding: 5vh 20vw 0 24vw;
    }
    #stackoverflow {
        margin-left: 9vw;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
{   
    .blocking {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

I want the elements to all stay well-centered, to have five-in-a-row on a full-sized monitor, but then slide nicely together when the screen is smaller. I can't figure out how to get them to stay centered on phone-sized screens. Any examples of *completely different* ways to handle what I'm doing would be appreciated - even if the end result is different. But if there is a way to properly tweak what I'm trying to do, that would be appreciated too.

EDIT: http://kennethfrancis.com

Comment: Why use `<td>` inside a div, without a table?! You also forgot the `>` after `<div class="blocking"`.

Comment: The icons seem well centered to me, even on the smallest resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your HTML, it has some problems in logic and syntax, I think.
this is a simple sample of what you can do:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/MG9U2/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/120" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/120" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/120" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/120" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/120" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    width:80vw;
    text-align:center;
}
a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with the centering on your current page.  I would recommend using Bootstrap to build your site though.  It'll give you the same responsive features you're looking to implement without requiring you to write all of the CSS mark-up.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxH9A/) of the sample HTML code you posted running on Bootstrap 3 without all of the CSS you wrote:

```
<div id="content" class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <a href="https://github.com/kfrncs"><img src="http://kennethfrancis.com/img/github.png" class="social" id="github"></a>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-4">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/kfrncs"><img src="http://kennethfrancis.com/img/twitter.png" class="social" id="twitter"></a>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <a href="mailto:kennethpatrickfrancis@gmail.com"><img src="http://kennethfrancis.com/img/gmail.png" class="social" id="gmail"></a>
          </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <a href="skype:kennethpatrickfrancis?add"><img src="http://kennethfrancis.com/img/skype.png" class="social middle" id="skype"></a>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2837229/kfrncs"><img src="http://kennethfrancis.com/img/stackoverflow.png" class="social" id="stackoverflow"></a>
      </div>
```

In the example, move the left border on the bottom right hand screen to see the icons stack and de-stack based on the document width

Answer (score 0):

dude,
first of all your html is very bad,
you CANNOT place  inside a 
the  MUST be inside a 
second, you have an open div, the one with the blocking class, dont know if you just copied it wrong but check it up anyway.

third, if you just want 5 rows with centered content just use 5 divs and each div takes a widht 100% and text-align center css attributes and that's it